# Qt5 convert QImage to OpenGL format

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qt5

In Qt4 there was a nice little function `QGLWidget::convertToGLFormat(QImage &img)`. If I am using Qt5 with OpenGL `QWindow` what should I use to convert the image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`QGlWidget` is still available for use (`QGLWidget` is the only `QGl*` class not deprecated in Qt5 looks like)

beyond that there is a new [QOpenGlTexture](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qopengltexture.html) class that has functions taking QImages directly.